# Accessing each line using a $ sign in linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix, pipe, sh

Whenever I execute a linux command that outputs multiple lines, I want to perform some operation on each line of the output. generally i do

```
command something | while read a
do
  some operation on $a;
done
```

This works fine. But my question is, Is there some how I can access each line by a predefined symbol( dont know how to call it) /// something like $? .. or .. $! .. or .. $_

Is it possible to do

```
cat to_be_removed.txt | rm -f $LINE
```

is there a predefined $LINE in bash .. or the previous one is the shortest way. ie.

```
cat to_be_removed.txt | while read line; do rm -f $line; done;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`xargs` is what you're looking for:

```
cat to_be_removed.txt | xargs rm -f
```

Watch out for spaces in your filenames if you use that one, though.  Check out the [xargs man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) for more information.

Comment: `xargs rm -f < to_be_removed.txt` and save a process.

Comment: I misread the command line - ignore my comment!  (Must be getting close to bed-time if I missed that!)

Answer (score 5):

You might be looking for the [`xargs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html) command.

It takes control arguments, plus a command and optionally some arguments for the command.  It then reads its standard input, normally splitting at white space, and then arranges to repeatedly execute the command with the given arguments and as many 'file names' read from the standard input as will fit on the command line.

Comment: +1 for the explaination. However, I didn't get the part where you said `repeatedly execute` the command. Doesn't `xargs` execute the command just once.

Comment: @Jaypal, most systems have a maximum command line length limit.  `xargs` will do "the right thing" and execute the command multiple times if necessary to work around that limit.

Comment: Thanks @CarlNorum. Got it .. didn't really read Jon's answer well, he did say `as many file names read from the STDIN as will fit on the command line`. Sorry about that. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 rm -f $(<to_be_removed.txt)
```

This works because `rm` can take multiple files as input. It also makes it much more efficient because you only call `rm` once and you don't need to create a pipe to `cat` or `xargs`

On a separate note, rather than using pipes in a while loop, you can avoid a subshell by using process substitution:

```
while read line; do
  some operation on $a;
done < <(command something)
```

The additional benefit you get by avoiding a subshell is that variables you change inside the loop maintain their altered values *outside* the loop as well.  This is not the case when using the pipe form and it is a common gotcha.

Comment: Unfortunately, both `$(<file)` and `< <(command)` are bashisms.  Do not use.

Comment: +1 for an alternate solution. @Zack Is there a reason why we shouldn't be using them? Why is the possible downside?

Comment: @Zack considering this question has the bash tag, I think using bashims is pretty safe

Comment: @SiegeX I agree. I still haven't found major pit-falls of process substitution. All I [found](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) was there could be a portability issue (but I guess most shells do support it now) and that we cannot get exit codes. Any other pit-fall you can think of?

Comment: @JaypalSingh nope, mostly it's just the portability thing as it's not POSIX. However, if you're using `bash` might as well take advantage of the syntax it supports.

Comment: Sorry for not answering a direct question for so long -- basically, I think that the bash extensions to POSIX shell don't add sufficient value to make them worth memorizing, and I actually find it useful to limit myself to a *subset* of POSIX shell roughly defined as "what you could do with the shell and utilities that shipped with Solaris 2.5.1".  Yes, that's ancient -- but it means I am never tempted to do something in shell that would be better done in Python or C.  The modern conveniences, in my opinion, just trap you into trying to do stuff in shell that you shouldn't have.

Comment: To be clear, it's not that the "modern conveniences" *themselves* are bad -- it's that they don't fix any of the deep flaws of the Bourne shell language, but they *do* tempt you to write bigger, more complicated shell scripts that are more likely to trip over those deep flaws.